# Got Error While Re-index Using CLI in magento How To resolve it

Tags: magento-1.9, error, reindex

I have run the command to re-index all the data using CLI but i got this Error:

```
Next exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= 'abs', ( - i.price), IF( = 'fixed', , ROUND(i.price * ( / 100), 4)))), 0) AS `' at line 1' in /chroot/home/quickpro/quickpromos.com/html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:234
```

How To resolve it, i have tried by deleting all the files in Var/locks But still no luck
Please Help

Answer (score 0):

Try re-indexing each index separately instead of all at once. Find the specific index that is throwing the error, then you may be able to narrow the cause down further.

Comment: Yeah I did this and found that "Product Prices " this Process is doing some issues and generating the above mentioned error @novusweb